# Jquery add sum total not happening with dynamically created content

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dynamically-generated

I have a form and when I enter a number and "keyup" it should display the total. However as long as the form is static it works fine but if dynamically generated it does not work.

I've added a js fiddle link, Any help mu appreciated

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scorpion_rain/38vM9/1/)

```
<form class="order-form">
<div class="product-lines">
    <!-- Product Line Section -->
    <div class="product-line">  <a href="#" alt="close" class="btn-close" title="Remove"><img alt="remove" src="img/close.png" /></a>

        <input class="input-text" name="product-code" type="text" placeholder="Product Code"></input>
        <input class="input-text" name="product-quantity" type="text" placeholder="Quantity"></input>
        <input class="input-text" name="product-discript" type="text" placeholder="Discription of Product" disabled></input>
        <label class="label-sign">&pound;</label>
        <input class="input-text" name="product-price" type="text" placeholder="RRP Price"></input>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
<p>Line below dynamically generated</p>
<div class="product-lines">
    <!-- Product Line Section -->
    <div class="product-line">  <a href="#" alt="close" class="btn-close" title="Remove"><img alt="remove" src="img/close.png" /></a>

        <input class="input-text" name="product-code" type="text" placeholder="Product Code"></input>
        <input class="input-text" name="product-quantity" type="text" placeholder="Quantity"></input>
        <input class="input-text" name="product-discript" type="text" placeholder="Discription of Product" disabled></input>
        <label class="label-sign">&pound;</label>
        <input class="input-text" name="product-price" type="text" placeholder="RRP Price"></input>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="product-btn">
    <input name="btn-add-line" type="button" value="Add new line"></input>
    <input id="btn-update" name="btn-update" type="button" value="Update"></input>
    <!-- Clear All Button -->
    <input id="btn-removeAll" name="btn-removeAll" type="reset" value="Remove All"></input>
    <input name="btn-submit" type="submit" value="Submit Order"></input>
    <label class="label-sign">&pound;</label>
    <input class="input-text" name="order-total" type="text" placeholder="Order total" disabled></input>
</div>
```

My Code

```
var productLines = $("div.product-lines"),
    productLine = $("div.product-line"),
    productPrice = $("input[name=product-price]"),
    productCode = $("input[name=product-code]"),
    productQuan = $("input[name=product-quantity]"),
    updateTotal = $("input#btn-update"),
    orderTotal = $("input[name=order-total]");



$(productLines).on("keyup", function (event) {

    var sum = 0;

    $(productPrice).each(function () {

        sum += Number($(this).val());

    });

    $(orderTotal).val(sum);


});
```

I am a JS newbie.

Answer (score 2):

Delegate the event to a higher-up element. If your `form` element is wrapped within a `section` element, for example, you can instead use:

```
$('section').on('keyup', 'div.product-lines', function(event) {
    ...
});
```

See [Event Delegation documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)  for details of how delegation works in jQuery.

Also `input` elements are self-closing. `<input ...></input>` is invalid and should be replaced with `<input ... />`.

Comment: Thanks! I am just removing the </input> tagas and checking the code, will check and let you know.

Comment: I tried my my case $(".content").on(...) and also as James Duffy suggested $(document).on(...) but it still does not total. It only outputs the first line. Help most appriciated.

Comment: @Zinox try calling the `keyup` event on the `input` elements themselves. You're currently calling it on the `div` element, and `div` elements have no `value` attribute.

Comment: Do you mean like this? <input onkeyup="myFunction()" />

Answer (score 0):

After you create a new line you have to update the `productPrice` var.

```
productPrice = $("input[name=product-price]")
```

Comment: @McCheeselt How do I go about doing that? Sorry im a JS newbie.

Comment: you can run the above code. on page load if you have 2 product-price fields your productPrice will contain 2 items. If you dynamically add another product-price field your productPrice var will still have 2 items and will not contain the newly added item. make sense?

Comment: @McCheeselt I have a var like that on the top after document load, however it still only take the first line and it does not add up.

Answer (score 0):

To bind events to dynamically inserted elements, try:

`$(document).on("keyup", "div.product-lines", function (event) {`

This syntax binds the event listener to the document itself, whereas `$(productLines).on("keyup", function (event) {` only binds to the elements that currently exist on the page when that line of code fires.